# SQLite: String interpolation using variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, string-interpolation

I am making an `ajax` request in my Rails 4 app and I cannot get my search query to function properly.  I have 1 search that works where I query:

```
list = list.where(TARGET_NAME like :search or BAR like :search, search: "%#{params[:search]["value"]}%")
```

which outputs the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "list" WHERE (TARGET_NAME like '%x%' or BAR like '%x%')
```

I have another search where the thing being searched is also a variable and I tried to copy the query above with the following:

```
list = list.where(:column like :search, column: $other_list[col[0]], search: "%#{col[1]["search"]["value"]}%"
```

which outputs the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "list" WHERE ('TARGET_NAME' like '%x%')
```

Due to the fact that `TARGET_NAME` is in quotes in the query, I get 0 results returned.  **How do I inject a variable there without the quotes?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a way to accomplish this with the variable, but I simply replaced the variable `:col` with `$other_list[col[0]]` making the request:

```
list = list.where("#{$other_list[col[0].to_i]} like :search", search: "%#{col[1]["search"]["value"]}%")
```